# Line breaks within a figure environment in memoir

Tags: floats, memoir

I am trying to set up the following layout on a figure in a document typeset with the memoir class:

[image]

I have tried using `\\` within the `\subbottom` environment, but this doesn't seem to work

```
\begin{figure}[!t]
\subbottom[]{
\includegraphics[width=0.45\linewidth]{img1.png}\\[0.2cm]
\includegraphics[width=0.45\linewidth]{img2.png}}
\hfill \subbottom[]{
\includegraphics[width=0.45\linewidth]{img3.png}\\[0.2cm]
\includegraphics[width=0.45\linewidth]{img4.png}}
\end{figure}
```

LaTeX seems to ignore my `\\[0.2cm]` commands and instead it tries to print images in the same row.

Is there a way to do this when using the float commands provided by the memoir class? (such as `\subbottom`).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `minipage`s inside `\subbottom`:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}

\newsubfloat{figure}
\newsubfloat{table}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\subbottom[]{%
\begin{minipage}{.45\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{img1.png}\\[0.2cm]
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{img2.png}
\end{minipage}
}%
\hfill \subbottom[]{%
\begin{minipage}{.45\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{img1.png}\\[0.2cm]
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{img2.png}
\end{minipage}
}%
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The `demo` option was only used to produce black rectangles instead of actual figures; do *not*a use that option in your actual document.